# 3D models show up as boxes

Tags: modeling, objects, import

So I'm complete new to using Blender Cycles. I've seen others do it. I've watched tutorials. I've tried googling help. I've spent hours worth of time trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to find anyone who has had my problem: I'm using Blender Cycles 2.79, I've gotten the XPS tools, I've activated them in my user preferences and all that fun stuff. My goal is to import already made 3d models (like Xnalara) into blender so I can practice posing them. But every time I try to import the model onto my main screen to work with, it just creates another box/square and an error pop-up (unboundlocalerror: local variable 'imagefilepath' referenced before assignment). I've downloaded programs like python and file viewer if that helps. But I'd like to know what exactly I'm doing wrong or if there's something else I need to get these models actually working on blender.

I have downloaded the latest version of xps tools. Would this help for a better understanding?

[image]

Comment: knowing nothing about XPS tools I would say that an image file referenced in the file being imported does not exist.

Comment: this sounds more like a Python error within the Add-on. Have you tried downloading the latest version at https://github.com/johnzero7/XNALaraMesh ?